# How to relate $|\delta x|$ and $|\tilde\delta x|$ in an inequality $A\le |\tilde\delta x|\le B$ where $A$ and $B$ contain $|\delta x|$?

Tags: inequality, error-propagation

$|\delta x| = |(\tilde x - x)/x|$  (this is the absolute value of relative error)

$|\tilde\delta x| = |(\tilde x - x)/\tilde x|$ (bound for some distinct quantity)

I need to find an inequality which relates these in this way:

$A\le |\tilde\delta x|\le B$ where $A$ and $B$ contain $|\delta x|$.

I know $\tilde x = x(1 + \delta x)$ or $\delta x = \delta(x)/x = (\tilde x - x)/x$

No idea how to proceed with finding that inequality though. Thank you very much if you can show me how this is done.

Comment: Hi, a tilde above a preceeding character say `$\delta$`$\delta$ can by typed by writing `$\tilde\delta$`$\tilde\delta$. And, please type the *entire* equation in between one pair of dollar signs `$...$`. Also, $\le$ is typed using `$\le$`. This is called LaTeX (more precisely on this website, Mathjax). You can get started [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I typed it for you this time so that you can use it as an example in future

Comment: @CalvinKhor thank you very much! That is helpful to know for the future. Do you happen to know the answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$|\tilde\delta x| = |\delta x| \frac{|x|}{|\tilde x|}.$$
From the first equation in the question,
$\left| \frac{
\tilde x}{ x}-1\right| = |\delta x| $,
so by triangle inequality, we obtain $$\frac{|\tilde x|}{|x|}  \le 1 + \left| \frac{\tilde x}{ x}-1\right| = 1+|\delta x|,$$
and
$$ \frac{|\tilde x|}{| x|} \ge 1 - \left| \frac{\tilde x}{ x}-1\right| = 1-|\delta x|.$$
Thus
$$ \frac{|\delta x|}{1+|\delta x|}\le |\tilde \delta x | \le \frac{|\delta x|}{1-|\delta x|}.$$

Comment: Thank you. When you said "from the first expression" and then stated an equation - where did that equation come from exactly? How did you find it? Also, how are you employing the triangle inequality here? Thanks again.

Comment: @Arcturus7 by the "first expression" I meant the first equation in your question, namely
$$ |\delta x| = |(\tilde x - x)/x|$$ (Technically this is an equation and not an expression,  so I will edit to change it. Sorry for the confusion)
By simplifying the fraction on the right, you get $|\frac{\tilde x}x-1|$. The triangle inequality is employed like this for the first one
$$ |t| = |(t-1)+1| \le |t-1| + 1 $$
and like this for the second one
$$ 1 = |1-t + t| \le |t-1| + |t| \implies |t| \ge 1 - |t-1|$$ 
These work for all $t$, in particular $t=\tilde x/x$

Comment: Genius! Thank you again @CalvinKhor

Comment: @CorwinofAmber you're welcome!